# Lost spaces in strings with CSV to array function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, csv, multidimensional-array, spaces

I am working with a function that converts csv data to a multi-dimentional array. I am then going through the characters to find specific situations in the way the strings are handled in the array. One example is if I have a string like - "this is a string, yeah" - then I make sure not to count the comma in the string because it is between quotes from that string. Anyhow In the following function I have some how lost my spaces in the results. Instead of getting "this is AS3" I am getting "thisisAS3". Spaces seem to only be available in the strings that have quotes. Anyone have an idea of where the issue in this portion of code is?

```
        function CSVtoArray(csv:String):Array {
        var inQuotes:Boolean = false;
        var field:String = "";
        var finalData:Array = new Array();
        finalData.push(new Array());
        var line:int = 0;
        //iterate each character
        for(var i:int = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
            var c:String = csv.charAt(i);
            var n:String = csv.charAt(i+1);
            var ad:Boolean = false;  
            //if the quote repeats, add the character
            if(inQuotes && c == "\"" && n == "\"") {
                field += c; 
            }            
            //if we are inside quotes, add the character
            if(inQuotes && c != "\"") {
                field += c;    
            }     
            //if we are not inside quotes...
            if(!inQuotes && c != "\"") {
                //if this character is a comma, start a new field
                if(c == ",") {
                    finalData[line].push(field);
                    field = "";   
                //if this character is a newline, start a new line
                } else if(c == "\n") {
                    finalData[line].push(field);
                    finalData.push(new Array());
                    line++;
                    field = "";     
                //if this is not leading or trailing white space, add the character
                } else if(c != " " && c != "\t" && c != "\r") {
                    field += c;
                }            
            }      
            //if this is a quote, switch inQuotes
            if(c == "\"") {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
            }      
        }      
        //add last line
        finalData[line].push(field);
        //if the last line does not have the same length as the first, remove it
        if(finalData[line].length < finalData[0].length) finalData.pop();



        //return the resulting array
        return finalData;

    }
```

Thanks for any help on this it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you could use a Tokenizer class, or some parser already in existence.

When I execute your function as:

```
var result:String = CSVtoArray("\"this is a string, yeah\"");
```

It works as expected - I get a string with spaces.

Your logic only functions for quoted strings:

```
//if we are not inside quotes...
if(!inQuotes && c != "\"") {
// ...
    //if this is not leading or trailing white space, add the character
    } else if(c != " " && c != "\t" && c != "\r") {
        field += c;
```

If you are not in quotes, and the character is not whitespace is it added.

So, when you are not in quotes and encounter whitespace is it not appended to the string.

Actually, this can be accomplished with 1-line of RegEx.

Expanding on [Taytay's](http://taytay.com/?p=106) one-line CSV parser, here's an example implementation:

**CsvParser.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class CsvParser extends Sprite
    {
        public function CsvParser()
        {
            var set1:Array = CSVtoArray("\"this is a string, yeah\"\n");
            var set2:Array = CSVtoArray("this is a string, yeah\n");
        }

        public function CSVtoArray(csv:String):Array
        {
            // split csv in to rows
            var rows:Array = csv.split("\n");

            // for every row...
            for (var x:uint = 0; x < rows.length; x++)
            {
                var columns:Array = csv.split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/g);

                for (var y:uint = 0; y < columns.length; y++)
                {
                    // trim leading / trailing whitespace
                    columns[y] = columns[y].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                }

                rows[x] = columns;
            }

            return (rows);
        }

    }
}
```